# Calling a macro from within another macro slows execution

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow up on a duration I posted yesterday "Why does this code causes an infinite loop"

Running "SortByEcode" first takes 5.51 seconds
Running "KeepEcode" next takes 1.65 seconds

But if I call "SortByEcode" from within "KeepEcode", KeepEcode takes 4min 54sec to run.

```
Sub EcodeKeep()
'Needs REH to be sorted first by ECode
TurnOffFunctionality           ' Turn off Calculations, DisplayStatusBar, EnableEvents and ScreenUpdating
     Dim i As Long
     Dim j As Long
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim StartTime As Double

      'Sort REH by ECode first
     Call SortByEcode                   'THIS IS STILL THE BIG PROBLEM

     Dim wks As Worksheet
     Set wks = rawData5            'Work in sheet("RawEquipHistory")
     LastRow = wks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     StartTime = Timer

     Dim Ecodes() As Variant
     Ecodes = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value)
     Dim Results As Variant
     ReDim Results(UBound(Ecodes) - 1)

     wks.Range("AM1") = "ECODE KEEP"  'Add the header to "S1"

     For i = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results) - 1
          Results(i) = Ecodes(i + 1) <> Ecodes(i + 2)
     Next i

     'wks.Range("AM2:AM" & i + 1).Value = Results 'I cannot get this line of code to work at all, so added a "write" loop
                                                                  ' outside of maim loop

     For j = 0 To i
          wks.Range("AM" & j + 2) = Results(j)
     Next j

TurnOnFunctionality            ' Turn back on at the end
Call EndTimer("EcodeKeep", StartTime)
End Sub
```

```
Sub SortByEcode()
TurnOffFunctionality           ' Turn off at the start
      Dim LastRow As Long
     LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawEquipHistory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawEquipHistory").Sort               '  SORT sheet by E-Code(a)
          .SortFields.Clear
          .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Order:=xlAscending
          .SetRange Range("A1:AZ" & LastRow)
          .Header = xlYes
          .Apply
     End With

TurnOnFunctionality            ' Turn back on at the end
Debug.Print "SortByEcode is Done"
End Sub
```

Also, I cannot get the line of code provided by Mathieu Guindon @MathieuGuindonto run at all. The code does not kick up any errors but every cell in Range("AM2:AM" & LastRow) equals TRUE. However, if I loop over the Range("AM2:AM" & LastRow)and write the values one at a time I get the correct values.

And if I loop and debug.Pring Results(i) I get the correct results in the immediate window. So I know that the Results array has correct values.

```
wks.Range("AM2:AM" & i + 1).Value = Results
```

Comment: You call ```turnonFunctionality``` at the end of ```SortbyEcode``` that might affect it, depending on what kind of events and calculations you have going, as they now run for the duration of ```EcodeKeep```.

Comment: @Warcupine That was it! Thanx so much.  Now I just need to resove the ```wks.Range("AM2:AM" & i + 1).Value = Results``` issue